# Finding out whether events are correlated

Tags: correlation, predictive-models, interaction

I manage software development. We have a lot microservices and have built a lot of features. I would like to see if any of the microservices are highly coupled - which I'm defining here as meaning that a change in one microservice is likely to trigger a change in another.

The data (which for now is completely made up) might look something like this:
[image]

In the intersection of a service and feature, I've got the number of updates that were made to the service in support of t hat feature. For instance, Feature E required 2 updates to Service 7.

Notice that there were 3 features that required at least 1 update to Service 3. All three of those features also required an update to Service 8. So maybe that means the Services 3 and 8 are coupled.

What is an effective test to identify which services are coupled?

Comment: Have you heard of cross-correlation? In a basic sense, it estimates the degree to which two series are correlated.

Comment: @signsandsymbols i have not. i will look into it. is it fair for me to assume that "series" doesn't necessarily mean "time series"?